# my scrapy framework was wrong when i was in crawl

Tags: scrapy

I built the scrapy framework on my mac, and everything went well, but when I followed the tutorial in scrapy, it went wrong when I typed in scrapy crawl dmoz. My Python version was 3.6 Mac version was 10.13.6. How do I fix it?
The error message is as follows:

```
kennethdeMBP:spiders kenneth$ scrapy crawl dmoz
2018-08-15 17:56:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2018-08-15 17:56:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.3.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) - [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2018-08-15 17:56:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2018-08-15 17:56:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-08-15 17:56:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2018-08-15 17:56:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py", line 5, in <module>
    from urllib2 import _parse_proxy
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib2.py", line 220
    raise AttributeError, attr
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
kennethdeMBP:spiders kenneth$
```

Comment: You might have more luck raising an issue [on Github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues), issues there seems to get attention.

Answer (score 0):

The module was renamed in Python 3 to urllib. So in import you need to change to the following.

- from urllib import _parse_proxy

Comment: I just contacted the scrapy framework, where did I change it?